# React App is not diplaying in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

There is an empty screen in the Internet Explorer when opening ReactApp. Even `noscript` tag content is not displaying.

So far I tried to add meta tag for IE and installed and included ReactApp polyfill. But no result and no change in the console. Still Syntax Error.

Is there anyone who could make it work. I agree to show at least `noscript` text, if there are any disadvantages to support IE browsers.

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Are you running your app on IE < 11

Comment: So here's a couple of things to note: Using polyfills will add things like classes or functions that don't exist in older browsers. For example `Number.isNaN` or `String.prototype.endsWith`. That sort of thing. **They will not make new syntax available to old browsers**. If you're using `class` then it won't be able to add classes to Internet explorer. This is for babel to do with the [env preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) . Just make sure you're targetting the correct browsers and note as a minimum you need IE 9 , possibly 10 for some things

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no, running in IE11. I have added polyfill for IE11 and IE9

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for your answer! You helped me with the understanding of polyfills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add polyfills for that. 
For more info, you can see here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill.
or you can add cdn of polyfill https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js.